# Importing python library which is installed in another python

Tags: python, import, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to import a python(python2.7.15) library arcpy, which is not installed on my main python but installed on an another python(version 2.7.12) (which came with arcgis automatically).

Now I am writing a python script which I want to run through main python but also import arcpy from another python (the arcgis one), how can I do that?

I have tried `from "thepath/to/arcgispython/python.exe" import arcpy`
but did not work.

Please note that I can not install arcpy in main python.

Comment: in your script 2.7.15 you would have to add folder with this library to `sys.path` and then use `import` in script to load it. But maybe easier will be install module in new version or use virtual environment in 2.7.15 to create separated 2.7.15 and then install module in this separated 2.7.15

Comment: I did `sys.path.insert()` but same import error

Comment: what path gives you `import arcpy` `print(arcpy.__file__)` ? What path did you insert to `sys.path` ?

Comment: The command gives me `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py` but I have inserted the location of another python.exe.

Comment: Have you tried `sys.path.append("module")` yet?